# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mecab.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, mecab

I tried installing the mecab-python-windows package both from source and via pip on a Windows 64-bit machine. I get the following error in both cases:

```
    MeCab_wrap.cxx(3137): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mecab.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`
```

How can I deal with this error? Where could I find the mecab.h file and where should I place it? I would really appreciate any suggestion! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`mecab-python-windows` is not maintained, development has moved to `mecab` on PyPI. See [here](https://qiita.com/yukinoi/items/990b6933d9f21ba0fb43), which also mentions the error you are getting. It suggests you do this:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=`python-config --prefix`/Headers:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH pip install mecab
```

I would suggest you use mecab-python3.